# removing logical and direct duplicate in a file through spark sql and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

consider a text file having two columns

```
a,b
c,d
a,b
a,b
d,c
b,a
e,f
g,h
```

with the help of spark-sql and scala on spark i have to remove the logical and 
direct duplicates.
in the above data for a record a,b
direct duplicate is a,b
logical duplicate is b,a
I know how to remove a direct duplicate, but i don't know how to remove logical duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below using `RDDs`

```
val inpurRdd=sc.textFile("H://spark//input.txt")
inputRdd.map(_.split(",").sorted.mkString(",")).map(x=>x->1).groupByKey.map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With RDD can be solved via elements comparison:

```
  val data = List(
  ("a", "b"),
  ("c", "d"),
  ("a", "b"),
  ("a", "b"),
  ("d", "c"),
  ("b", "a"),
  ("e", "f"),
  ("g", "h"))
val original = sparkContext.parallelize(data)

val converted = original.map(v => if (v._1 < v._2) (v._1, v._2) else (v._2, v._1))
println("-- converted -- ")
converted.foreach(println)

println("-- result --")
converted.distinct().foreach(println)
```

Output is:

```
-- converted -- 
(c,d)
(a,b)
(a,b)
(c,d)
(e,f)
(a,b)
(g,h)
(a,b)
-- result --
(e,f)
(a,b)
(g,h)
(c,d)
```

Comment: what if instead of elements "a","b" I have names

Comment: if names are strings, provided code have to work fine, if names are in the same case. Otherwise, names in uppercase can be used for comparison.